# Cucumber + Capybara tests to ensure a new window is opened

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

I have the following lines in my feature file:

```
Given I have website "www.google.co.uk" 
When I click the website "www.google.co.uk" 
Then "www.google.co.uk" page is opened in a new window
```

I am struggling to find a way to test that the webpage is definately opened in a new window.

Currently I have been using this in my step def:

```
Then /url "([^"]*)" is opened in new window/ do |url|
  browser = page.driver.browser
  current_id = browser.window_handle
  tab_id = page.driver.find_window(url)
  browser.switch_to.window tab_id
  page.driver.browser.close
  browser.switch_to.window current_id
end
```

but this still passes the test if the webpage is loaded on the same page, I want it to fail if the webpage is loaded on the same window/tab.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see no assertions in your test.

My approach would be to test size of `window_handles` array after performing clicking action on the link, since before clicking the size should equal 1 and after the clicking `window_handles` should equal 2.

```
assert page.driver.browser.window_handles.size == 2
```

Imho, good enough, since if the webpage is loaded in the same tab, the size will be 1 and the test will fail.

Comment: CHeers for that mate. That was perfect. I am just starting out with cucmber+capybara and agile tbh. But again thanks for your help, it has cleared up other things for me too.